# Removing Duplicate IN SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have 4 columns A,B,C,D. I need to remove the duplicates from where column A alone is the primary key. Duplicates can be in 1 or 2 or 3 values of B,C,D.

Eg:

```
A B C D
--------    
1 1 1 1
1 1 2 1
1 1 2 1 (COLUMN IS DUPLICATE BECAUSE VALUE IN C IS SAME)
1 1 2 2
1 1 2 2 (COLUMN IS DUPLICATE BECAUSE VALUES IN C AND DIS SAME)
```

Expected result

```
A B C D
-------
1 1 1 1
1 1 2 1
1 1 2 2
```

Comment: How is `A` the primary key? There are multiple rows with `A=1`

Answer (score 3):

Based on the description I can say that simple distinct should help:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C, D FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is indeed the primary key, then you want something like this:

```
select min(a) as a, b, c, d
from t
group by b, c, d;
```

Note:  In your sample data `A` is not a primary key.

If you want to delete the duplicates, then:

```
delete from t
    where t.a > (select min(t2.a)
                 from t t2
                 where t2.b = t.b and t2.c = t.c and t2.d = t.d
                );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but I need to remove it from my base table